# Copy file between two VMware guest OS

Tags: vmware-workstation

[image]

I want to copy a file from Vmware Guest OS (win7 32bit) to another Vmware Guest OS (win7 64bit). But I got the above error. Any solution for this?

I used VMware® Workstation 12 Pro.

Comment: Try to share the local drive for both 2 VMs

Comment: How would you copy files between two real hardware devices? Store on a shared NAS? NFS mounts (or Samba for windows), sFTP, rsync,.... All these options also work between to VMs.

Comment: How did you tried to copy the file? Did you used Sharedfolder etc.?

Comment: Now I used shared folder

Answer (score 3):

This error is a common one. What you have to do is copy the file from the first vm(win7 32bit) to the host computer(the computer you are running vm worksation) and then copy from the host to the second vm (win7 64bit).

The above method is pleasable for small  files, but when it comes to big files, sharing it on your network will be much easier.

Comment: Yes I use it now.